# Reference to class is ambiguous when compiling with g++4.5.2

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, systemc

I need a bit of help here: when using g++ 4.1 to build my code, there was no error regarding "reference to class is ambiguous". It only happens when using g++4.5.2 to compile the same code, and here is the code fragment:

```
#include "tlm_utils/simple_initiator_socket.h"

using tlm_utils::simple_initiator_socket;

class HvEcu : public sc_module {
public:
           ......
    simple_initiator_socket<HvEcu> initiator_socket;
//object instantiated here, also problem happend here....
            ......
};
```

I am really not sure why this would happen as syntax for namespace is valid for sure.
There is a fix to get rid of that message,and this is instead of "using tlm_utils::simple_initiator_socket;" just put "tlm_utils::simple_initiator_socket initiator_socket;" in the body of class shown above. However I don't see why the above code does not work given the only change is compiler version.

Comment: Your code isn't enough to know exactly what the problem is, but I assume that you have a class named simple_initiator_socket in the main scope, and that GCC is confused.

Comment: @MaëlNison: Wouldn't that fail for both compiler versions?

Comment: Maybe that 'old' versions of GCC were assuming that the using statement would mean that the developer explicitely wants to use the namespaced simple_initiator_socket ? I'm not really sure, but it could be an explanation.

Comment: @MaëlNison: Interesting. user960095, could you try removing the using line to see how it reacts? Or use `tlm_utils::simple_initatior_socket<HvEco>` as the type of the field inside the class?

Comment: @Maël Nison the issue is: class HvEcu is declaration is not finished before trying to initialize initiator_socket with HvEcu type in template

Comment: What's the full error description including references to the classes?

Comment: @billz I don't think so, it's definitely not the same error message : http://codepad.org/ol3j1kHN

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an explicit call:

```
class HvEcu : public sc_module {
    tlm_utils::simple_initiator_socket<HvEcu> initiator_socket;
```

**Lesson of the day:** Stay up to date with compiler changes and use the most recent stable one. Otherwise, you'll end up writing old incorrect code; and encounter other side effects of the compiler.

Comment: as I mentioned before, it works and builds when leaving the using line up there, but when compile in 4.5.2, the fix is to remove the using line and do tlm_utils::simple_initatior_socket<HvEcu> in the body instead. The question is WHY, why the original version is not recognised anymore???

Comment: @user960095: There appears to be another `simple_iniatior_socket` present, bit without other code we can't tell why.

Comment: yeah, that is part of the TLM standard library.